# Solving separable system of differential equation in three variables

Tags: mathematical-economics, difference-equations

I have the following system of differential equations:

$$ m \sqrt{y(x, z)} + \left( \frac{nz}{\sqrt{1-y(x, z)}} + \frac{mx}{\sqrt{y(x, z)}}\right)y_{1}(x,z) = 0 $$

$$ n \sqrt{1-y(x, z)} + \left( \frac{nz}{\sqrt{1-y(x, z)}} + \frac{mx}{\sqrt{y(x, z)}}\right)y_{2}(x,z) =0 $$

How can I solve them?

Can I solve them separately?

Any resource or hints will be helpful.

Comment: This might have more success on the math exchange.